# How to merge a map of types into a single flat type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

## What I need

I have an undetermined number of mods in an input object:

```
const mod1 = {
  actions: {
    a() { },
    b() { },
  }
}

const mod2 = {
  actions: {
    c() { },
    d() { },
  }
}

const input = {
  mods: {
    mod1,
    mod2
  }
}
```

At run time, a lib merges the mods in a single object which is equivalent to:

```
const output = {
  actions: {
    a() { },
    b() { },
    c() { },
    d() { },
  }
}
```

And I would like to create a type that would describe this single object.

## What I tried

The input objects can be described like that:

```
interface Input {
  mods: Mods
}

interface Mods {
  [name: string]: Mod
}

interface Mod {
  actions: {
    [name: string]: () => void
  }
}
```

Then, I don't know how to merge the content of mods:

```
interface ToOutput<I extends Input> {
  actions: MergeMods<I["mods"]>
}

type MergeMods<M extends Mods> = // How to merge the content of 'M'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
type Output = ToOutput<(typeof input)["mods"]>

interface ToOutput<I extends Mods> {
  actions: UnionToIntersection<I[keyof I]["actions"]>
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
```

## Explanations

The following type:

```
interface ToOutput<I extends Input> {
    actions: UnionToIntersection<I["mods"][keyof I["mods"]]["actions"]>
}
```

first uses [`keyof` and lookups](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to map the `Input` type to match the  output structure

```
interface ToOutputStep1<I extends Input> {
    actions: I["mods"][keyof I["mods"]]["actions"]
}

/*
type T1 = {
    actions:
      | { a: {}; b: {}; }
      | { c: {}; d: {}; };
}
*/
type T1 = ToOutputStep1<typeof input>
```

and then converts the [`actions` union type to an intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type).

```
/*
type T2 = {
    actions: {
        a: {};
        b: {};
        c: {};
        d: {};
    };
}
*/

type T2 = ToOutput<typeof input>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=63&ssc=41&pln=59&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtiAJgRhgXhgbwFAzzAQ2CgEtwIAuLXfWggCgEosYBfAGhtrwCMmWOXNtlbZsoSLASIATOmp1iZSFRzd8wfpjad1eRFp1DRo8eVgkwABwCusDGvzTKCvdOS63SGcZFiJ0DAgdrb2rnhEpOSqQnSGgnowfMzaCXqaKUaJBplpeCZillAApgBOAGZExTAAktZ24fBILgCyzX7YRWWVwNVtiBCNANpgBHDFVNCllgDmALpU-R1dFVUw-Y2Ryi6O6iNjEzBTswsw-GgAfDAAbiAkiL6mUACeVtUAqmDKACogdSWlCDFJTgAA87yuaCE9HeMGKAA8SmABoQwM8YAB+M4Aayo72Ylxud0QMCoYGK1zKzARSJR9HouJglnKZVqBKut3uzCxNVJMHJlNKYgA9MKYAArGyBcogUpJYpQAEwF5vGAy0pwAiK2YwWylKwgIHsfkgEBWbAq6oAUXhVgIyNB30hMG+cMRxWRgxAPHFwKgQixrppHpRzNZAHlMSwhgBpJlgGDY4rPEDlGDh042u0O8OxuZXVh8gVlIRUb4AbkKYABPWqv3DITsAGUSlZkKDecHPbV6lArrtCCCVLUhgAiZyjuZDJMptM1McTuZT0dbciTjqWl2oDBZ+2IR0gBtQUIt4pt0GW1Px0IXC5VmtreuNqAdt20wZ1G+bIcuT4-P7VmUQJDh2C7NJO07Jle87juBS5jqukCTneTyvHWcg7rae4HkeoQXmhV6WDeFxAA)

Comment: Thank you. It works. I edited your answer to put all the minimal code from the playground.

Comment: Good hint to also include the `UnionToIntersection` type in the answer, somehow forgot that, thanks! I'll drop that `Expand` type here for illustration purposes, as it could confuse people - it's just to display the type more clearly in the IDE and doesn't change the actual type.